# Excel 2013 Pivot table not pulling in all rows

Tags: excel, pivot

So I imported a sql query from a database and I came back with around 80,000 rows. But when I create a pivot table for that data using all the fields, it only returns about 4,000 rows. How do I make it so that the pivot table contains all 80,000 rows?

Comment: Does the pivottable point to the correct # of rows?

Comment: In order to see the source criteria have the pivot table active - on the ribbon there will be a tab for pivot table, in that ribbon tab there will be an icon for source - say change source, you can specify the column/rows there.  I like to say A:X [x=last column] without a row count, making it flexible when refreshing the table.